# Academic Background for Switchtracking Phenomenon

Tags: social-psychology, bias

In [one recent episode of Hidden Brain podcast](http://www.npr.org/2015/09/22/434597124/trying-to-change-or-changing-the-subject-how-feedback-gets-derailed), they talk about a pattern in conversation called "Switchtracking". It references to the the "Thanks for the Feedback" book by Douglas Stone and Sheila Heen.

In general it happens when you get a feedback unrelated to the topic you are concerned in a conversation. Here is how it is defined at respective NPR post:

> Switchtracking, as defined by author Sheila Heen, is when "someone
>   gives you feedback, and your reaction to that feedback changes the
>   subject."

I'm wondering if there is any academic background supporting this phenomenon (There is neither references section in the book nor podcast page). Is it called something else in academia? I could not find any references to some academic publications in the fields of CogSci, management, or behavioral economics.

Comment: You see, I tried hard to find autoritative reference, but without success.

Comment: @FlaviadePaivaBritesMartins Thank you, *alignment* from cognitive linguistics seems somehow fit here, since they do not separate conceptual domain from language domain in cogling.

Comment: There is also a book "Thanks for the Feedback" that seems to be the source of switch-tracking idea (by the same authors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch-tracking seems very similar to the **"Dialogue Alignment"** in Psycholinguistics and some other fields of Cognitive Science. *For a successful conversation interlocutors need to develop similar representations*. Switch-tracking, however seems an abstract conceptual domain problem, but dialogue alignment mostly investigates issues in a more concrete linguistic domain.

Here are some related publications:

> - Pickering, M. J., & Garrod, S. (2006). Alignment as the basis for
>     successful communication. Research on Language and Computation,
>     4(2-3), 203-228.
> - Garrod, S., & Pickering, M. J. (2007). Alignment in dialogue. The
>     Oxford handbook of psycholinguistics, 443-451.
> - Brennan, S. E., Galati, A., & Kuhlen, A. K. (2010). Two minds, one
>     dialog: Coordinating speaking and understanding. Psychology of
>     Learning and Motivation, 53, 301-344.

And this one investigates bilingual alignments:

> - Purmohammad, M. (2015). Linguistic alignment in L1–L2 dialogue.
>     Language and Dialogue, 5(2), 312-333.